# ddclient updates every time and logs 'nochg: No update required'

Tags: ddclient

I have installed ddclient on my server and it seems to work. However, I get these warnings in my syslog:

```
nochg: No update required; unnecessary attempts to change to the current address are considered abusive
```

Obviously, ddclient fires the update even if the IP address check returns the same address as last time. How can I change this to have it do the update only if the address has actually changed since the last run?

Here is my `/etc/ddclient.conf`, with some information redacted:

```
daemon=300
syslog=yes
verbose=yes
protocol=dyndns2
use=web, web=dns.loopia.se/checkip/checkip.php, web-skip='Current IP Address:'
server=dns.loopia.se
ssl=yes
login=<redacted>
password='<redacted>'
<redacted>
```

Answer (score 1):

**ddclient** uses a cache to check if your public IP address changed from your last report.

Only if it changed it will send the new one.

You might have an error in your cache file. Remove it to let ddclient create a new clean cache file.

```
 sudo rm /var/cache/ddclient/ddclient.cache
```

Comment: I this something you know from experience or discovered from somewhere else? If you could point out to a reference that would help others in the future and raise the confidence on your answer.